# Trying to align 2 implies conditions

Tags: amsmath

I have been unsuccesful to align the 2 right arrows in the following code:

```
\begin{align*}
& F_{1}(\lambda): \\ 
& \begin{cases}
    \Delta_{1} \geq 0 \\
    F_{1}(1)>0 \\
    F_{1}(-1)>0 \\
    -2 < \lambda^{1}_{1,1}+\lambda^{1}_{1,2} < 2 \\
    -1 < \lambda^{1}_{1,1}\lambda^{1}_{1,2} < 1
\end{cases}
& \implies 
    \begin{cases}
        |g_{c}(a+b)+1+t(1-2\epsilon)| \geq 2\sqrt{\eta(1-2\epsilon)}\\
        \epsilon < \frac{1}{2} \\
        g_{c}(a+b) < 1+(\frac{\eta}{2}-t)(1-2\epsilon) \\
        -1 < g_{c}(a+b)+t(1-2\epsilon) < 3 \\
        -1 < g_{c}(a+b)-(\eta-t)(1-2\epsilon) < 1
    \end{cases} \\
& F_{2}(\lambda): \\
& \begin{cases}
    \Delta_{2} \geq 0 \\
    F_{2}(1)>0 \\
    F_{2}(-1)>0 \\
    -2 < \lambda^{1}_{2,1}+\lambda^{1}_{2,2} < 2 \\
    -1 < \lambda^{1}_{2,1}\lambda^{1}_{2,2} < 1
\end{cases}
& \implies 
    \begin{cases}
        |g_{c}(a-b)+t+1| \geq 2\sqrt{\eta}\\
        \eta > 0 \\
        1-g_{c}(a-b)-t+\frac{\eta}{2} > 0 \\
        -1 < g_{c}(a-b)+t < 3 \\
        -1 < g_{c}(a-b)-\eta+t < 1
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
```

Always the right arrows are coming unaligned.one from the other.

Any help is welcomed!

Comment: N alignment points require 2N – 1 ampersands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the end of the alignment columns with another `&`. Adding a `&` after the first `cases` environment of each row, we get the following result.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
& F_{1}(\lambda): \\ 
& \begin{cases}
    \Delta_{1} \geq 0 \\
    F_{1}(1)>0 \\
    F_{1}(-1)>0 \\
    -2 < \lambda^{1}_{1,1}+\lambda^{1}_{1,2} < 2 \\
    -1 < \lambda^{1}_{1,1}\lambda^{1}_{1,2} < 1
\end{cases} &
& \implies 
    \begin{cases}
        |g_{c}(a+b)+1+t(1-2\epsilon)| \geq 2\sqrt{\eta(1-2\epsilon)}\\
        \epsilon < \frac{1}{2} \\
        g_{c}(a+b) < 1+(\frac{\eta}{2}-t)(1-2\epsilon) \\
        -1 < g_{c}(a+b)+t(1-2\epsilon) < 3 \\
        -1 < g_{c}(a+b)-(\eta-t)(1-2\epsilon) < 1
    \end{cases} \\
& F_{2}(\lambda): \\
& \begin{cases}
    \Delta_{2} \geq 0 \\
    F_{2}(1)>0 \\
    F_{2}(-1)>0 \\
    -2 < \lambda^{1}_{2,1}+\lambda^{1}_{2,2} < 2 \\
    -1 < \lambda^{1}_{2,1}\lambda^{1}_{2,2} < 1
\end{cases} &
& \implies 
    \begin{cases}
        |g_{c}(a-b)+t+1| \geq 2\sqrt{\eta}\\
        \eta > 0 \\
        1-g_{c}(a-b)-t+\frac{\eta}{2} > 0 \\
        -1 < g_{c}(a-b)+t < 3 \\
        -1 < g_{c}(a-b)-\eta+t < 1
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```